# App script populates google slides with data from sheets, creates images and URL but only once script has completed

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script which takes data from google sheets and populates google slides with the name and number of guests. It then saves those images as thumbnails and can be emailed (but I removed the email part from my script). Before the script is complete, it fills in each URL in line with each guest name. However, the URL will only be filled in once the entire script has completed.

App script has a restriction on runtime for each script which you run. If there are too many guest names to fill out, then the application times out and this means that the URL do not get pasted into the cell even though they were created.

I wish to edit this code so that it may paste the URL in each row before moving to the next row. I also want to add in an if function so that if there is already data in the cell, it can overwrite the data. Presently, if there is data in the cell, the script won't do anything but no error codes are shown.

```
function changeSlideTextAndDuplicate() {
  var presentationId = "11i9F3qH-xX1c4FGO6cSSAaTGNwTRowk-6W183lntLRA"; // Please set your presentation ID of Google Slide.
  var folderId = "1q0zcPGCttQkMrG14HdtORsahcJwkBnGA"; // Please set your folder ID. The images are saved into this folder.

  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); // In this case, the active sheet is used. If you want to use the specific sheet, please modify this to SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("###Sheet name###")
  var range = sheet.getRange("A4:C" + sheet.getLastRow());
  var presentation = SlidesApp.openById(presentationId);
  var templateSlide = presentation.getSlides()[0];
  var values = range.getDisplayValues().map(([name, guests, url]) => {
    if (!name || !guests) return [""];
    if (name && guests && url) return [url];
    var newSlide = presentation.appendSlide(templateSlide);
    newSlide.getShapes()[0].getText().setText(name);
    newSlide.getShapes()[1].getText().setText("No. of Guests: "+guests);
    presentation.saveAndClose();
    var { contentUrl } = Slides.Presentations.Pages.getThumbnail(presentationId, newSlide.getObjectId(), { "thumbnailProperties.thumbnailSize": "LARGE" });
    var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(contentUrl).getBlob().setName(name);
   
    presentation = SlidesApp.openById(presentationId);
    return [folder.createFile(blob).getUrl()];
  });
  range.offset(0, 2, values.length, 1).setValues(values);
}
```

Comment: I think you should remove the  `presentation = SlidesApp.openById(presentationId);` that is in the loop at the bottom it's not doing anything that I can tell and it's wasting a lot of ttime.

Comment: What's is keeping you from making the desired changes on your own?

Answer (score 0):

I don't work with slides much but I think this will work for you if in fact the function is working for you now. This will run much slower than your current function but it will be loading each row one at a time.

```
function changeSlideTextAndDuplicate() {
  const presentationId = "11i9F3qH-xX1c4FGO6cSSAaTGNwTRowk-6W183lntLRA"; 
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1q0zcPGCttQkMrG14HdtORsahcJwkBnGA");
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const rg = sh.getRange("A4:C" + sh.getLastRow());
  const presentation = SlidesApp.openById(presentationId);
  const templateSlide = presentation.getSlides()[0];
  rg.getDisplayValues().forEach(([name, guests, url], i) => {
    let r;
    if (!name || !guests) {
      r = [""];
    } else if (name && guests && url) {
      r = [url];
    } else {
      let newSlide = presentation.appendSlide(templateSlide);
      newSlide.getShapes()[0].getText().setText(name);
      newSlide.getShapes()[1].getText().setText("No. of Guests: " + guests);
      presentation.saveAndClose();
      let { contentUrl } = Slides.Presentations.Pages.getThumbnail(presentationId, newSlide.getObjectId(), { "thumbnailProperties.thumbnailSize": "LARGE" });
      let blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(contentUrl).getBlob().setName(name);
      r = [folder.createFile(blob).getUrl()];
    }
    sh.getRange(i + 4, 3).setValue(r);
  });
}
```